MongoDB nextauth

Hi! I have two web apps that share this database. Both of them have authentification using nextauth. The problem i have is that when i connect on one application i get dissconected from the other because they share the same session, account, users collections. My question is what can i do to solve this?
I tried something like this,forcing some custom names for those collection but it is creating those collection as before, no change.
export const authOptions=({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      authorizationUrl: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/authorize?response_type=code&prompt=login`,
  }),
  ],
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise, {
    collections: {
      users: "app2_users",
      accounts: "app2_accounts",
      sessions: "app2_sessions",
      verificationTokens: "app2_verificationTokens"
    }
  }),
    callbacks: {
      signIn: async (user, account, profile) => {
        try {
          const adminEmails = await fetchAdminEmails(); // Await the asynchronous function
          console.log('adminEmails', adminEmails);
  
          if (adminEmails.includes(user.user.email)) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false; // If return false, the signin will be denied
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error checking admin status:', error);
          return false; // Return false if an error occurs
        }
      },
    },

})  

